Connect your Nest.js application to SQL Server using LDAP authentication via a Linux server
I still get error "Login failed for user".
I want to connect with SQL data.
I write this code in app.module.
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

import { User } from './users/users.model';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'uploads'), // Path to the folder where your files are uploaded
      serveRoot: '/uploads', // Route at which the files are served
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
     
      dialect: 'mssql',
      host: 'sql ip', // Your SQL Server host
      port: sql port,           // Your SQL Server port
      username: '',         // Leave empty if using Windows Authentication
      password: '',         // Leave empty if using Windows Authentication
      database: 'NEWDCC-v3', // Your SQL Server database name
      dialectOptions: {
        options: {
          encrypt: true,     // Set to true if SQL Server requires encryption
          trustServerCertificate: true, // Use this if your SQL Server uses self-signed certificates
          // This will tell Sequelize to use Windows Authentication
          authentication: {
            type: 'ntlm',    // NTLM authentication
            options: {
              domain: 'ldap domin', // Replace with your AD domain
              userName: 'my user name',    // LDAP username
              password: 'my password ',  // LDAP password
            },
          },
        },
       
        },
     
     
      models: [
       
        User,
       
      ],
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: (msg) => console.log(msg),
    }),
   
    UsersModule,AuthModule
   
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }

And did Linux Server Configuration:
Install LDAP Client Packages:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ldap-utils libnss-ldap


Have you checked the SQL Server logs for the true authentication error? What was that error? What about the error didn't you understand?

@ThomA i  got (Login failed for user '' )
i want connect to sql database without user &pass via ldap

That isn't the full authentication error, please give us the full error that tells us why the login failed.

this is the error in my log ( refused connection with empty username )

[Nest] 30  - 08/06/2024, 11:24:49 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 30  - 08/06/2024, 11:24:50 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +176ms
[Nest] 30  - 08/06/2024, 11:24:50 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 30  - 08/06/2024, 11:24:50 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 30  - 08/06/2024, 11:24:50 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.
@ThomA

Those aren't SQL Server logs. We can't help you if you can't tell us what the authentication error is. The login could have failed for many reasons.

okay ... sorry now i understand you
i find this error in sql log
"login failed for user "Reason An attempt to login using Sql autherntication failed .
Server is configured for integrated authentication only [client]"

Have you tried to remove the username and password properties from the top level of the configuration object? By including them as blank strings you're probably telling the mssql library to attempt an SQL Login with a blank username and password.

i did that but still get the same error
